# Como colocar transição em um dropdown de um menu?

Tags: jquery

Atualmente utilizo o seguinte código:

```
$("#menu").find('li').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('ul').clearQueue().slideDown(600);
    $(this).children('a').children('ul').clearQueue().show(0);
}, function () {
    $(this).children('ul').slideUp(300);
    $(this).children('a').children('ul').hide(0);
});

$("#menu").find('a').has( "ul" ).each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("menu-arrow");
});
```

Ele usa o `.slideDown` e o `.slideUp`. Como eu poderia deixá-lo como o [deste site](http://www.megahost.com.br)?

[image: exemplo animado do menu]

Quando passa o mouse pelo menu, abaixa os `dropdowns`.

Como é o nome dessa função? Eu poderia substituí-la pelo `.slide`...

[*Código HTML no Pastebin*](http://pastebin.com/sxBpK6cY).

Comment: CSS puro já resolve, dê uma olhadinha: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Comment: Prefiro com jQuery. Pois não são todos os navegadores que funcionam só com CSS.

Comment: O que exatamente tem de diferente entre o que você está fazendo e o que você quer fazer? Tem um demo que a gente possa olhar? (ex.: jsFiddle) Vi no site indicado que eles não usam jQuery (a resposta do bupereira mostra qual é a biblioteca e a função que eles usam). E pelo pouco que li do seu código, me parece que ele está fazendo mais ou menos a mesma coisa, não? Se tem diferença, não percebi...

Comment: Eles usam sim jQuery. Abra o site com o Google Chrome, coloque inspecionar elemento, e você verá que o menu irá ficar mudando o valor de `top:` fazendo com que ele suba e desça.

Comment: Sim @mgibsonbr usando o `.slide` ele só muda o **height**, já no site que dei exemplo, ele muda a posição `top:` que é muito mais bonita.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes Agora estou sem tempo pra te orientar melhor, mais tarde eu volto aqui. Enquanto isso, sugiro procurar pelos demos no jQuery no que diz respeito a "Effects" e "Easing". Com eles, deve dar pra customizar o `slide` para que os submenus apareçam e desapareçam da forma como você quer (passando parâmetros adicionais pro `slide` além da duração).

Comment: Não sei. Não sou muito bom com jQuery. Você poderia dar uma força... Rsrs

Comment: Você tem um exemplo de HTML pra eu testar? Eu custei pra entender o que você quer (a animação é rápida, então não vi a princípio a diferença), talvez fosse bom editar a pergunta esclarecendo isso (falo da questão do `height` e do `top`). O jsFiddle está offline pra mim ([e aparentemente, só pra mim...](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/jsfiddle.net)), mas depois eu tento montar um exemplo. Esquece o que eu falei sobre "Effects" e "Easing", isso que você quer provavelmente vai envolver o [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: tem como postar o css também? da pra fazer facilzinho com jQuery isso

Comment: @RodrigoBorth é complicado postar o CSS. Não teria como só adaptar pelo jQuery que eu coloquei na pergunta?

Comment: @AlexandreLopes to sem tempo pra conseguir fazer um exemplo funcional, mas o que você precisa fazer é só dar um slideDown no mouse over e slideUp no mouse out, se você usar a função hover do jQuery ja vai ficar assim o efeito, só precisa ajustar a velocidade depois

Comment: Mas dá uma olhada no meu jQuery. Eu já uso o `slideUp` e `slideDown`. Só que não fica igual o exemplo que citei.

Answer (score 4):

Não sei se ajuda, mas o source em JS pra função showMenu é esse aqui:

```
ypSlideOutMenu.showMenu = function(id)
{
var reg = ypSlideOutMenu.Registry
var obj = ypSlideOutMenu.Registry[id]
if (obj.container) {
obj.over = true
for (menu in reg) if (id != menu) ypSlideOutMenu.hide(menu)
if (obj.hideTimer) { reg[id].hideTimer = window.clearTimeout(reg[id].hideTimer) }
if (!obj.open && !obj.aniTimer) reg[id].startSlide(true)
}
```

Peguei da pagina do próprio site, em 
http://www.megahost.com.br/paginas/js/ypSlideOutMenusC.js

Espero que ajude em alguma coisa.
Murilo

Answer (score 4):

O código abaixo é uma simples amostra do que você talvez pretende fazer. No entanto, vale ressaltar que ela apenas realiza transição em menus de apenas dois níveis e esta não é a solução ideal para smartphones. Para atingir o máximo de dispositivos possíveis dentro dos padrões da W3C, recomendo-lhes melhorar a HTML, CSS e JavaScript. Como não tenho muito tempo, desenvolvi uma solução bem simples.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Meu menu</title>
        <style type="text/css"><!--
            .menucontainer {
                background: #eee
            }
            ul.menu, ul {
                list-style: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                display: block
            }
            ul.menu a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: inherit
            }
            ul.menu li {
                display: block;
                float: left;
                position: relative;
                padding: 10px
            }
            ul.menu li:hover {
                background: #ddd
            }
            ul.menu li li {
                float: none;
                padding: 0
            }
            ul.menu li li a {
                padding: 10px;
                display: block
            }
            ul.menu li .verticalhider {
                position: absolute;
                top: 90%;
                left: 0;
                overflow: hidden
            }
            ul.menu li ul {
                display: none;
                background: #f3f3f3;
                width: 200px;
                padding: 5px;
                border: 1px dotted #555;
                position: relative
            }
            ul.menu li:hover ul {
                display: block
            }
            .clearfix {
                clear: both
            }
        //--></style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
            (function($){
                $(function(){
                    $('.menu li > .verticalhider > ul').each(function(){
                        var u = $(this);
                        function getHeight(){
                            return u.height() + parseInt(u.css('paddingTop')) + parseInt(u.css('paddingBottom')) + parseInt(u.css('borderTopWidth')) + parseInt(u.css('borderBottomWidth'))
                        }
                        u.css({display: 'block', marginTop: -getHeight()}).parent().parent().mouseenter(function(){
                            u.stop().animate({marginTop: 0}, 200)
                        }).mouseleave(function(){
                            u.stop().animate({marginTop: -getHeight()}, 200)
                        })
                    })
                })
            })(jQuery);
        //--></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="menucontainer">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>
                    <span>Menu 1</span>
                    <div class="verticalhider">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Menu 2</span>
                    <div class="verticalhider">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Até mais

Comment: Só é para computadores mesmo, para smartphones estou usando o plugin jQuery SlickNav.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes A propósito, o exemplo dessa resposta parece fazer exatamente o que você quer ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/5qotLkuc/)). Você teve algum problema para adaptá-lo ao seu caso particular? Ou talvez faltou alguma coisa?

Comment: Acho que o correto seria editar a resposta, ao invés de citar um exemplo, que pegasse o código que eu mencionei na pergunta e adaptá-lo. Não sou bom com `jQuery`, então não sei como adaptá-lo. Na pergunta tem o `jQuery` e o `HTML`, queria que fosse adaptá-do no meu código.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes Bom, na minha concepção a ideia do SO é responder perguntas, a adaptação ao seu caso particular ainda é responsabilidade sua (entretanto, você é livre para não aceitar uma resposta que não te satisfaça). De minha parte, eu só não dou a recompensa pra essa resposta porque ela só joga o código e não explica, caso contrário eu aceitaria ela na hora. Eu vejo que essa técnica funciona, mas não entendo muito bem por que. Tem muitas regras CSS, sendo que a maioria delas me parece só dar suporte ao leiaute, não sendo central à solução do problema. Isso torna um pouco difícil adaptá-la.

Comment: :( ||||||||||||

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar, considere a possibilidade de uma solução via CSS puro, como [apontado por dxhj nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28963/como-colocar-transi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-um-dropdown-de-um-menu#comment54101_28963). Basta atribuir uma margem negativa ao submenu, e atribuí-la a zero quando o item de menu está sob o mouse (*hovered*). Pode-se adicionar efeitos de transição usando a propriedade `transition`, quando suportada ([a maioria dos browses a suporta, exceto por IE9 ou inferior](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)).

```
nav ul ul {
    margin-top: -120%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: margin 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: margin 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: margin 1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: margin 1s ease-in;
    transition: margin 1s ease-in;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahobngoe/). [Referência 1](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu), [referência 2](http://candpgeneration.com/toys/CSS3-dropdown-tut.php). Nota: sou pessimo com CSS, então o exemplo não ficou tão bom quanto poderia (o submenu chega por cima do menu), mas deve servir de base pra algo mais elaborado. Além disso, tentei usar seu HTML, mas ele contém um monte de erros, então adaptei como pude...

> P.S. [A resposta do Recovieira Coimbra Vieira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28968/215) parece resolver esse problema do `overflow` usando um elemento extra `.verticalhider`. Tentei reproduzir no meu exemplo, mas como a resposta não explica o raciocínio por trás da técnica, não consegui entender bem como ela funciona. De todo modo, aqui está [um exemplo funcional](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/5qotLkuc/) usando o código daquela resposta.

Caso seja mesmo necessário usar jQuery (nem que seja pros browsers que não suportam `transition`), pode-se adaptar o código do `slideDown` - que segundo [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3216268/520779) é feito através de uma chamada de `animate` - de modo a não variar o `height`, mas sim o `margin-top`:

```
$("nav > ul > li").hover(function () {
    $(this).children('ul').clearQueue().animate({
        //"height": "show",
        "marginTop": 0, //"show",
        "marginBottom": "show",
        "paddingTop": "show",
        "paddingBottom": "show"
    }, 1000);
    $(this).children('a').children('ul').clearQueue().show(0);
}, function () {
    $(this).children('ul').animate({
        //"height": "hide",
        "marginTop": "-120%", //"hide",
        "marginBottom": "hide",
        "paddingTop": "hide",
        "paddingBottom": "hide"
    }, 1000);
    $(this).children('a').children('ul').hide(0);
});
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahobngoe/1/).

Comment: Obrigado! Vou realizar alguns testes.

Comment: Eu coloquei aqui o seu `.animate` e ficou todo bugado. Ele não está nem um pouco parecido com o exemplo que dei. Quando tira o mouse de cima ele só sobe até a metade, depois ele some do "nada".

Comment: Como CSS não é o meu forte, vou deixar que alguém melhor nessa área responda então. Quanto a sumir do nada, creio que se você animar tanto o `height` quanto o `top` ajuda - ela só vai ficar 2x mais rápida (você pode ajustar o `delay` de acordo). Agora, quanto a subir até a metade, não dá pra adivinhar sem ver o seu markup... Se você prefere não mostrar, é um direito seu, mas nesse caso você está por sua conta.

Comment: Vou mostrar. Vou colocar do pastebin.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sxBpK6cY

Comment: @AlexandreLopes Não consegui, realmente sou péssimo com CSS, e não achei nada no jQuery que ajudasse... Mas também estou interessado numa resposta, por isso estou colocando uma recompensa nessa pergunta.

Comment: \o/ Legal!.....

Comment: mano tem como postar o código do seu CSS?

Comment: @AlexandreLopes Bom, falta poucas horas pra recompensa acabar, e ninguém se manifestou... Editei minha resposta com toda a informação que consegui juntar, inclusive um exemplo com seu código (adaptado; tem muitos erros de HTML nele, então não deu pra usá-lo como está).

Comment: :D Obrigado por tudo @mgibsonbr você é 10!

Comment: @mgibsonbr dei uma reestruturada no seu CSS, veja se aproveita algo: http://jsfiddle.net/ahobngoe/3 . Em resumo, eu usei um overflow:hidden no nav para eliminar a parte de cima do menu, e repensei um pouco a estrutura toda. Tirei um pouco dos detalhes extras (gradients, etc) para focar mais no CSS essencial, e reordenei por "profundidade" para facilitar a manutenção. Só preciso ver como fazer a _gambi_  do 180% ficar mais previsivel. (depois deleto esse comment aqui)

Comment: Uma versão com px em vez de %: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ahobngoe/6/