# Tem como fazer feature detection pra CSS?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Conheço a técnica de *feature detection* ("descoberta de funcionalidade") - bem como [*feature inference*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19010/215) - quando se trata de JavaScript:

```
if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) { ... }
```

Mas tem como fazer isso para CSS também? A exemplo [dessa outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28963/215), eu gostaria de criar um menu animado [somente com CSS](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu), mas a propriedade `transition` [não é universalmente suportada](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions). Eu poderia fazer tudo com jQuery, mas me parece um desperdício, uma vez que a grande maioria dos browsers suporta essa funcionalidade.

O ideal então seria detectar se há esse suporte, usando o jQuery como *fallback* caso não haja. É possível? E se a resposta for "não", seria esse um dos raros casos em que *browser detection* se justifica?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, é possível fazer feature-detection de CSS, tanto usando JavaScript, quanto com CSS puro (nesse caso tem seus próprios problemas de suporte cross-browser).

Por JavaScript, você simplesmente checa o objeto `style` de um elemento que tenha a propriedade ou valor em questão aplicada. Por exemplo, se o browser dá suporte a transições por CSS, a propriedade `transition` do objeto terá um valor diferente de `undefined`. Para mais precisão na verificação, não deixe de checar também as variantes prefixadas, como `-moz-transition` (a propriedade JavaScript nesse caso seria `MozTransition`).

Este [exemplo da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations/Detecting_CSS_animation_support) verifica se o browser dá suporte à propriedade `animation`, verificando um elemento `elm`:

```
var animation = false,
    animationstring = 'animation',
    keyframeprefix = '',
    domPrefixes = 'Webkit Moz O ms Khtml'.split(' '),
    pfx  = '';

if( elm.style.animationName !== undefined ) { animation = true; }    

if( animation === false ) {
  for( var i = 0; i < domPrefixes.length; i++ ) {
    if( elm.style[ domPrefixes[i] + 'AnimationName' ] !== undefined ) {
      pfx = domPrefixes[ i ];
      animationstring = pfx + 'Animation';
      keyframeprefix = '-' + pfx.toLowerCase() + '-';
      animation = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Com CSS puro, existe o [`@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) que funciona como uma *media query*. Porém, [o suporte ao `@supports` é limitado](http://caniuse.com/#search=@supports). Mais um exemplo da MDN:

```
@supports ( not ((text-align-last:justify) or (-moz-text-align-last:justify) ){
    … /* specific CSS applied to simulate text-align-last:justify */
}
```

É bom lembrar que a biblioteca [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) utiliza internamente essas duas técnicas, e oferece atalhos práticos para verificar o suporte a diversas propriedades CSS.

Comment: +Nota 100 pra este par P&R+ . . . [*Meanwhile*](http://i.imgur.com/3cJVOjl.jpg)

Comment: Yo Dawg, I herd you like to test for support using `@supports`, so [I created a `suportaSupports`](http://jsfiddle.net/mr37zmkx/) so you can test for `@supports` support to use `@supports` to test for support. (testado no Chrome e no IE)

Comment: um detalhe, eu acompanhei o outro tópico.... a biblioteca do site que o rapaz utiliza como exemplo de menu que ele queria fazer, tambem utiliza a biblioteca Moderniz